# Can I skip a json tag while Marshalling a struct in Golang?

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

I have a scenario where I would like to skip a json tag while marshalling a struct in Golang. Is that possible? If so how can I achieve this?

For example I am getting this json:
`{"Employee":{"Interface":{"Name":"xyz", "Address":"abc"}}}`

But I want the json to be:
`{"Employee":{"Name":"xyz", "Address":"abc"}}`

Comment: `Employee:{Interface:{Name:"xyz", Address:"abc"}}` is not JSON though, and neither is the other thing. That looks like the output of `fmt.Printf("%+v", e)` which is a different thing from JSON. You should be more clear in what you want help with.

Comment: You're right, I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Interface` field's type is *not* an actual interface but a struct type then you could embed that field, this will promote the embedded struct's fields to `Employee` and marshaling that into JSON will get you the output you want.

```golang
type Employee struct {
    Interface // embedded field
}

type Interface struct {
    Name    string
    Address string
}

func main() {
    type Output struct{ Employee Employee }

    e := Employee{Interface: Interface{Name: "xyz", Address: "abc"}}
    out, err := json.Marshal(Output{e})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/s5SFfDzVwPN

---

If the `Interface` field's type *is* an actual interface type then embedding won't help, instead you could have the `Employee` type implement the `json.Marshaler` interface and customize the resulting JSON.

For example you could do the following:

```golang
type Employee struct {
    Interface Interface `json:"-"`
}

func (e Employee) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type E Employee
    obj1, err := json.Marshal(E(e))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    obj2, err := json.Marshal(e.Interface)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // join the two objects by dropping '}' from obj1 and
    // dropping '{' from obj2 and then appending obj2 to obj1
    //
    // NOTE: if the Interface field was nil, or it contained a type
    // other than a struct or a map or a pointer to those, then this
    // will produce invalid JSON and marshal will fail with an error.
    // If you expect those cases to occur in your program you should
    // add some logic here to handle them.
    return append(obj1[:len(obj1)-1], obj2[1:]...), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XsWZfDSiFRI

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the second solution you gave worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous structures

```
type Employee struct {
    Interface Interface
}
type Interface struct {
    Name string
    Address string
}
func main() {
    a := Employee{Interface: Interface{Name: "xyz", Address: "abc"}}
    b := struct {
        Employee Interface
    }{
        Employee: a.Interface,
    }
    jsonResult, _ := json.Marshal(b)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonResult)) // {"Employee":{"Name":"xyz","Address":"abc"}}
}
```